# Merging several Flux into one from Mongo Collection

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, project-reactor

I am a bit new to spring reactive programming. I am currently developing an app using spring-boot-starter-webflux:2.0.0.M5.

I have a Foodtruck mongodb model which contains menus :

```
@Document(collection = "Foodtruck")
@lombok.Getter
@lombok.Setter
@lombok.NoArgsConstructor
@lombok.AllArgsConstructor
public class Foodtruck {
  @Id
  private String id;

  @URL
  private String siteUrl;

  @NotBlank
  private String name;

  private String description;

  @NotBlank
  private String address;

  private List<Menu> menus;

  @JsonIgnore
  private GridFS image;
}
```

And here is the model for Menu :

```
@lombok.Getter
@lombok.Setter
@lombok.NoArgsConstructor
@lombok.AllArgsConstructor
@Document(collection = "menus")
public class Menu {

  @Id
  private String id;

  private List<DayOfWeek> days;

  @NotBlank
  private String label;

  private String description;

  private Double price;

  private List<Dish> dishes;

  @JsonIgnore
  private GridFS image;
}
```

To get all my menus, I first need to get all my restaurants and then merge all the *Flux* obtained, and return them through my rest controller.

Here is the service I call from my rest resource :

```
@Service
public class MenuServiceImpl implements MenuService {

  FoodtruckService foodtruckService;

  public MenuServiceImpl(FoodtruckService foodtruckService) {
    this.foodtruckService = foodtruckService;
  }

  @Override
  public Flux<Menu> getAllMenus() {
    Flux<Menu> allMenuFlux = Flux.empty();
    Flux<Foodtruck> foodtruckFlux = foodtruckService.getAllFoodtrucks();

    foodtruckFlux.toStream().forEach(foodtruck -> {
      Flux<Menu> currentMenuFlux = Flux.fromIterable(foodtruck.getMenus());
      allMenuFlux.mergeWith(currentMenuFlux);
    });

    return allMenuFlux;
  }
}
```

The mergeWith does not seems to add anything to *allMenuFlux*. I think I have an understanding problem here.

I have been through the documentation, tested other methods like concat or zip, but it does not interleave flux events as I wish. I can't manage to merge these *Flux* correctly.
I also think there is a better way to get mongo embedded documents through a *menu* repository, since my method seems to be a bit overkill, and can cause performance problems in the long run. I have tried and it does not work.

EDIT: 
After trying the following code (Being sure that my list is not empty), the resulting *fluxtest3* variable is merged correctly :

```
Flux<Menu> allMenuFlux = Flux.empty();
Flux<Foodtruck> foodtruckFlux = foodtruckService.getAllFoodtrucks();

List<Foodtruck> test = foodtruckFlux.collectList().block();

Flux<Menu> fluxtest1 = Flux.fromIterable(test.get(0).getMenus());
Flux<Menu> fluxtest2 = Flux.fromIterable(test.get(1).getMenus());
Flux<Menu> fluxtest3 = fluxtest1.mergeWith(fluxtest2);
```

But that's not exactly what I want. Why isn't it working with an empty flux as parent flux.

What am I missing here ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: did you try use, map instead toStream/foreach?
foodtruckService.getAllFoodtrucks().flatMap(foodTrack -> Flux.fromIterable(foodtruck.getMenus()));

This return a flux, and you no need any conversion

Comment: Well it's working, thanks !. As I understanding, flatmap extracts the Flux<Menu> for all my foodtrucks and returns it as a unified Flux. So it's kind of merging everything. Is that it ? Maybe you can formulate a complete answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there are a couple of misunderstandings at work here.

1. If you ever convert a `Flux` to a  `Collection`, `Stream` or similar and then something obtained from that back to a `Flux` you are most certainly doing something wrong. These classes force your pipeline to collect multiple elements, then process them and then convert them back to a `Flux`. In almost every case this should be possible just with operations offered by `Flux`.
2. The methods on `Flux` don't change the `Flux` but create new instances with additional behavior. So if you have code like this:

   ```
   Flux<Menu> allMenuFlux = Flux.empty();
   Flux<Foodtruck> foodtruckFlux = foodtruckService.getAllFoodtrucks();

   foodtruckFlux.toStream().forEach(foodtruck -> {
       Flux<Menu> currentMenuFlux = Flux.fromIterable(foodtruck.getMenus());
       allMenuFlux.mergeWith(currentMenuFlux);
   });
   ```

   return allMenuFlux;

   Everytime you call `allMenuFlux.mergeWith(currentMenuFlux);` you create a new    `Flux` just so the Garbage Collector can take care of it. `allMenuFlux` is still the empty `Flux you started with.
3. What you really seem to want is:

   ```
   return foodtruckService.getAllFoodtrucks()
       .flatMap(Foodtruck::getMenus);
   ```

   See the documentation for [`flatMap`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-). The difference between `flatMap` and `mergeWith` is that `mergeWith` keeps the original elements. Which is superfluous if there are none as in your use-cases.

Bonus: Your additional question

```
Flux<Menu> fluxtest1 = Flux.fromIterable(test.get(0).getMenus());
Flux<Menu> fluxtest2 = Flux.fromIterable(test.get(1).getMenus());
Flux<Menu> fluxtest3 = fluxtest1.mergeWith(fluxtest2);
```

Here you are not returning the original `fluxtest1` but the newly generated `fluxtest2`. Therefore it does work.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your detailed answer. It's working now, and I know why it didn't work earlier.